# Unable to set "Main view" as ContentView in Android project with VS 2015

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin

I'm facing issues with Visual Studio 2015 when developing an Android Application.

For some reason I'm not able to set my Main view in MyActivity

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Id.Main);
    }
```

When building it returns the error "'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'Main'", although the view is called "Main.axml"
I did have this issue before, but could solve that by saving the view, which always helped.

I'm not sure, but it looks like it has something to do with a recent update of Xamarin.

I've tried several things: Clean solution, Rebuild (ends in error), Closing VS and re-open, restart computer.
I've also created a new project, but that didn't help either.

Below is my (simple) Main.axml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/read"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="read" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try delete the bin and obj, and restart your VS. If it also can't work, please use VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
}
```

because you are referring to a layout you want that activity to look. Not a specific view in a layout.